# Flex MenuBar : Stay open on itemclick

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, menubar

I have a *MenuBar* with objects that have children of type="*check*". E.g.:

Menu

- Menu Item A

  / List item Check 1A

  / List item Check 2A

  / List item Check 3A
- Menu Item B

  / List item Check 1B

  / List item Check 2B

My question is as follows: How can i avoid the MenuBar from hiding when the user clicks an item (itemClick event)? I want the user to be able to "check" several items at once, without the menu hiding/closing.

Bonus question: What is the easiest way to reset all the checked items? :-)

Best Regards,

Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can advise you is to do monkey patching of the class Menu. I have tried to do it by me, it works as you described in your task.

The main reason to do it is, that the functions we need to redefine use private members of this class. So we can't just override them.

The aim of our mission is to patch the function

```
function mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{...}
```

At its end you can see the call

```
hideAllMenus();
```

We should add a new variable to control whether or not our item is of type "check". So you need to add this line in the beginnig

```
var isCheck:Boolean = _dataDescriptor.getType(item) == "check";
```

and this condition at the end

```
if (!isCheck) hideAllMenus();
```

Don't forget to do a trick to let your patched class be loaded before the SDK's one.
You can read about it [here](http://www.jamesward.com/2009/03/10/flex-monkey-patching-and-framework-rsls/).

Here is my working [example](http://it-skills.su/sosamples/webspark46/menubar/SO_MenuBar.html). Menu1 has only check items and Menu2 only normal ones.

The whole project can be found [here](http://it-skills.su/sosamples/webspark46/CustomMenu.zip)

Comment: Thank you very much Anton. I will try this in the morning!

Comment: Hey Anton. Im currently attempting to implement the changes you suggested, and tried the monkey patch strategy. But currently it does not seem to work, so i'll have to try a bit more. But i was wondering if it was possible to see the source of the example you created? I think that would be of much help :)

Comment: Hello Sebastian, now you can find a link to the project at the end of my post.

Comment: It Worked!!! Dunno what i did wrong the first time, but when not it seems to work. Thank you so much for your help Anton!

Comment: The custom preloader of the application is very important to be able to load your custom Menu and not the SDK's one.